# How do I change a specific pixel on screen with C code that is linked to a bootloader assembly file?

Tags: c, operating-system

I want to change a pixel that is **smaller** than a cell in an 80 by 25 grid, so changing the cell's color wont work. The code that I could use takes up an entire cell, and you can't get much details, and clearing the screen constantly instead of just printing the color somewhere else is pretty inefficient.

If I didn't care about the pixel size, I would use:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>

const static size_t NUM_COLS = 80;
const static size_t NUM_ROWS = 25;

struct Char {
    uint8_t character;
    uint8_t color;
};

void define_pixel(uint8_t specifiedColor) {
    if (col > NUM_COLS) {
        print_newline();
    }
    buffer[col + NUM_COLS * row] = (struct Char)
    {
        character: (uint8_t) ' ',
        color: specifiedColor,
    };

    col++;
}
```

(knowing that I didn't get help for a single edited line of code in this means that there is probably a bug) 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're doing this for your OS kernel, have you checked one of the tutorials or examples on [the OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Expanded_Main_Page)? What you call "pixel" is simply a set of two bytes that is stored in memory at a specific address. Where the base address for this memory, how to find which bytes are for which character, and how to edit the contents of the specific bytes, are well-documented all over the Internet. And if you're reading a book to learn then it should have this information as well. And if you're in a class your teacher should have given you that information.

Comment: If you want a *true* pixel, then you need to enable graphics mode, which is a lot more work than just doing text-mode output. There are plenty of information about that as well, all over the Internet. And again, if it's an assignment from a book or in a class, you should have been given information about how to do it, or at least information about where to find documentation about it.

Comment: In text mode (80x25) the idea is that you only *want to* store the character code, and the graphics board will look up the corresponding pixels for you. This is a great advantage during boot up, as you can write text without first loading lots of code. On the other hand, it also limits what you can do when the images are predefined. So you can easliy change an `a` into a `b`, but there is no way to remove the dot from an `i`.